# How do I use multiple Kynetx apps in a single phone call with Twilio?

Tags: twilio, krl

I want to be able to use multiple Kynetx apps (rulesets) in a single phone call. Say the first app is a phone menu, and the second app provides the functionality for the menu option. How do I redirect from one to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a twilio:redirect() or twill:gather_start() action, the url you provide is a relative URL.

All [twilio webhooks provided by Kynetx](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Twilio) have the full URL of `http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/appid/eventname`

If you pass in a URL relative to this, it will resolve relative to this. Example:

With a base URL of `http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/myappid/callstart` the action `twilio:redirect("sayhello")` will resolve to `http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/myappid/sayhello`

This will send in a new event to the same application.

If you want to switch apps, you can either provide the full URL, including the new appid, or use a relative URL like the following:

With a base URL: `http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/myappid/callstart` the action `twilio:redirect("../newappid/sayhello")` resolves to: `http://webhooks.kynetxapps.net/t/newappid/sayhello`

Here is an example app which uses a different app for a menu choice.

```
ruleset firstappid {
  meta {
    name "Phone Menu App"
    description <<
      Provides the Phone Menu
    >>
    author "Sam Curren"
    logging off
  }
  dispatch {}
  global {}

  rule menu {
    select when twilio givemenu
    {
      twill:gather_start("../secondappid/menuchoice") with numDigits = 1;
        twilio:say("Press 1 to speak do whatever.");
      twilio:gather_stop();
    }
  }
      
}
```

And the app which receives the menu choice.

```
ruleset secondappid {
  meta {
    name "Phone Menu Option"
    description <<
      Provides the menu functionality
    >>
    author "Sam Curren"
    logging off
  }
  dispatch {}
  global {}

  rule speak {
    select when twilio menuchoice Digits "1"
    {
      twilio:say("This is what you get when you press 1.");
      twilio:hangup();
    }
  }
}
```

By using the action `twilio:redirect('../firstappid/givemenu')` instead of `twilio:hangup()`, this rule could redirect back to the first app.

Comment: Love the full ruleset examples!

Comment: I tried to make them as simple as possible, while still showing the full app.